# Microphone is disabled/not working in app (converted from website)

Tags: javascript, html, css, microphone

(GOAL)

I am trying to convert my existing website into an android application.

The existing website has a functionality which uses microphone for voice audio input and outputs a result using javascript.
Currently the voice audio input will be captured through computer's microphone and is working fine.
I have also tested on android device by opening up the webpage and the voice input is also working fine.

---

(PROBLEM)

When the website was converted into apk using cordova and android studio, the microphone function did not work when installed on the device and running through the device.

To solve the issue I have tried to go inside 'App Permission' in the settings to add permission for microphone. This did not work as the options did not even show any options under 'ALLOWED' or 'DENIED'. Other applications such as Google Maps do show options such as 'Location' or 'Camera'. I am writing this to illustrate that I am looking in the right setting.

---

(BACKGROUND INFORMATION)

The website was made using html, css, javascript.
The website has SSL certificate which means microphone request is working fine on website.
The microphone functionality was done using the code below.

SpeechRecognition = window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition ;

Other solutions that I have looked at is to learn React Native to prompt the user to ask for permission for sensitive information.

---

(IDEAL SCENARIO)

Since my coding knowledge is very limited, learning other language would be a time consuming process. Ideally I would like to resolve this issue by:

- Only using javascript
- Convert website to app using other simple method to have the microphone to work.